# Single server with multiple JVMs and multiple GC algorithms

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot, g1gc, concurrent-mark-sweep

I have a single linux application server with 4 JVMs on it. The GC Algorithm that I use on them is CMS. Can i change the GC algorithm of two of those JVMs to G1GC ? Is there any negative impact by doing so ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have one machine (virtual or physical) on which you run 4 different JVM:s? If so, you can use whatever gc you want. There might be a negative impact, it might not be, it's impossible to say given the information given. 
If, on the other hand, you have a clustered application server running on a single host but 4 separate JVM:s, then different gc:s might very well produce strange effects but once again, try it out and measure.